# Missing data in SpatialPolygonDataFrames R: error in Moran.plot

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial-statistics

I'm trying to use Moran.plot on a SpatialPolygonDataFrame (the world map from the rworldmap package) consisting of 234 elements in R. My database contains 81 countries, so there are 162 codes in the map which are not represented in my data.

```
> worldmap <- joinCountryData2Map(database, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "code")
81 codes from your data successfully matched countries in the map
0 codes from your data failed to match with a country code in the map
162 codes from the map weren't represented in your data
```

First, I generate the spatial weight matrix for the 3 closest neighbors:

```
# Recovery of centroids from employment areas
coor <- coordinates(worldmap)

# Definition of the 3 closest neighbors
cartePPV3.knn <- knearneigh(coor, k=3) 
cartePPV3.nb <- knn2nb(cartePPV3.knn)
PPV3.w <- nb2listw(cartePPV3.nb, style = "W", zero.policy = TRUE)
```

Then when I try to plot the moran diagram the code below returns

```
> moran.plot((database$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE)
Error in moran.plot((database$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE) : 
  objects of different length
```

I also tried this solution, but it returns the same error

```
> my.na.omit <- function(z) z[!is.na(z)]
> moran.plot(my.na.omit(worldmap@data$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE)
Error in moran.plot(my.na.omit(worldmap@data$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE) : 
  objects of different length
```

The structure of my data is the following:

```
database<-structure(list(code = c("ARG", "ARM", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BEL", 
"BGR", "BHS", "BLR", "BOL", "BRA", "BWA", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", 
"CHN", "CIV", "COD", "COL", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DOM", "EGY", 
"ESP", "EST", "FIN", "FRA", "GAB", "GBR", "GHA", "GMB", "GTM", 
"HND", "HRV", "HTI", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "IRQ", "ISR", 
"ITA", "JAM", "JOR", "JPN", "KEN", "KOR", "KWT", "LBR", "LBY", 
"LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAR", "MEX", "MLT", "MWI", "MYS", "NLD", 
"NOR", "NZL", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "POL", "PRT", "PRY", "RUS", 
"SAU", "SDN", "SEN", "SWE", "THA", "TTO", "TUR", "VEN", "VNM", 
"YEM", "ZAF", "ZWE"), sales2010 = c(44287, 4, 185329, 20222, 
2019, 130775, 1123, 6584, 38, 994, 187351, 312, 600161, 275761, 
32645, 303281, 1275, 1642, 24004, 1781, 18636, 363995, 5960, 
14952, 100793, 446, 10643, 211677, 556, 658153, 1159, 2, 4762, 
5057, 556, 291, 19039, 34144, 65621, 271794, 209, 18539, 131316, 
987, 756, 303618, 658, 107154, 6531, 1537, 4311, 316, 28923, 
209, 1955, 227473, 1411, 469, 57286, 242155, 51486, 13592, 10907, 
13722, 21190, 40124, 13935, 1790, 41474, 26593, 1, 152, 32332, 
57996, 7505, 40122, 23803, 3069, 940, 36411, 168), gdp = c(423627422092.49, 
9260284937.79782, 1146138465603.81, 391892746544.69, 52902703376.1056, 
480951629493.033, 50610058210.3696, 10095760000, 5.87e+10, 19649631450.6819, 
2208871646202.82, 12786654365.8738, 1613542812589.39, 583783396408.582, 
218537551220.071, 6087164527421.24, 24884505034.5564, 21565720044.4634, 
286103648654.545, 25732432719.0773, 207477857918.919, 3396354075663.73, 
53860187452.8829, 218888324504.753, 1420722034063, 19685033799.4182, 
249181190476.369, 2642609548930.36, 14358584300.3006, 2475244321361.11, 
32174772955.9748, 1543292392.54605, 41338008612.7727, 15839344591.9842, 
59807966533.2848, 6622541528.56888, 131135561228.374, 755094160363.071, 
1675615335600.56, 222148757313.006, 138516722649.573, 233995676194.679, 
2134017843247.16, 13220556882.7046, 26795901408.4507, 5700098114744.41, 
40000088346.8041, 1094499338702.72, 115419050942.08, 1.998e+09, 
74773444900.5368, 37024718364.5516, 53212476812.2957, 23796118300.8371, 
93216746661.5977, 1057801295584.05, 8749171417.20801, 6959655570.89098, 
255016609232.871, 846554894931.084, 428757038466.841, 146583831538.331, 
29440300000, 147528937028.778, 199590775190.258, 479321460551.189, 
237880908317.652, 27215968615.5548, 1524917468442.01, 528207200000, 
65634109236.7736, 16215069255.5883, 495328620126.028, 341105009515.333, 
22157948396.2042, 771901768870.083, 393192354510.653, 115931749697.241, 
30906749533.221, 375349442837.24, 12041655200), gdppc = c(10385.9644319555, 
3218.37270660563, 52022.1255961876, 46858.0432733717, 5842.80578358576, 
44141.8781415734, 6843.26694975885, 28443.4076553352, 6181.4, 
1955.46155736098, 11286.2430162457, 6434.81565688465, 47450.3184700703, 
74605.7745091454, 12808.034586422, 4550.45359583857, 1211.93033804477, 
334.021572573152, 6326.54946861963, 30818.4799259532, 19808.0710912518, 
41531.9341978689, 5555.39094900238, 2644.81703909751, 30502.7197080776, 
14784.3810806949, 46459.9732548543, 40638.33400426, 8840.73066379785, 
39435.8399018505, 1298.43695159215, 860.637873688125, 2825.48396349692, 
1904.34646496881, 13923.6370524478, 665.627419493396, 13113.5259617277, 
3122.36281521649, 1357.56371913262, 48715.1768553933, 4657.28042580536, 
30693.5930786871, 36000.5201179254, 4704.05445468166, 3690.11326778672, 
44507.6763859172, 951.687961116879, 22086.9529193201, 38577.3816572031, 
513.445698620224, 12064.7806924218, 11953.9384416891, 104965.306078267, 
11344.6933695837, 2839.92516805933, 9271.39823324639, 21107.3644349639, 
478.668589704525, 9040.56625117172, 50950.0343435181, 87693.7900658099, 
33692.0108346543, 8082.02845866252, 5082.35475666351, 2124.05676974627, 
12599.5335818707, 22498.6908586557, 4355.93493867734, 10674.9972024225, 
19262.5476811757, 1489.87691083872, 1278.97775413162, 52817.441365794, 
5076.34299245077, 16683.3553787376, 10672.3892452162, 13825.3580883312, 
1317.89070617836, 1334.78484461341, 7328.61562893966, 948.33185445926
), population = c(40788453, 2877319, 22031750, 8363404, 9054332, 
10895586, 7395599, 354942, 9490583, 10048590, 195713635, 1987105, 
34004889, 7824909, 17062536, 1337705000, 20532950, 64563854, 
45222700, 1112612, 10474410, 81776930, 9695121, 82761235, 46576897, 
1331475, 5363352, 65027507, 1624140, 62766365, 24779619, 1793196, 
14630417, 8317470, 4295427, 9949322, 10000023, 241834215, 1234281170, 
4560155, 29741976, 7623600, 59277417, 2810460, 7261539, 128070000, 
42030676, 49554112, 2991884, 3891356, 6197663, 3097282, 506953, 
2097555, 32343389, 114092963, 414508, 14539612, 28208035, 16615394, 
4889252, 4350700, 3642687, 29027674, 93966780, 38042794, 10573100, 
6248020, 142849449, 27421461, 34545013, 12678148, 9378126, 67195028, 
1328147, 72326988, 28439940, 87967651, 23154855, 51216964, 12697723
), Export = c(81123016360.6088, 2210672987.38497, 260249450614.58, 
197754734995.671, 28234775000, 369294651391.053, 25303890000, 
3196008000, 2.93e+10, 6836994924.1346, 231995637790.95, 5273007889.77465, 
469288008080.745, 372127504216.421, 81955505335.345, 1603944171443.28, 
12593261961.1995, 8866500000, 45882895935.252, 12939073661.2597, 
137029742232.405, 1443337924604.33, 12270500000, 48831200000, 
368535746091.486, 14627605142.6957, 95846565511.4142, 709353195634.283, 
9340231071.72115, 700321794220.098, 9437380000, 270568875.315234, 
10803318404.5824, 4939311177.07018, 22345655941.7061, 1016384389.4025, 
107223068846.779, 166636323443.415, 348035371769.33, 207839505909.957, 
54593900000, 81456300000, 536026782436.075, 4004373830.42721, 
12751830985.9155, 869989651841.154, 8983066272.5496, 546783400000, 
76139508378.4144, 325037491.048954, 49345100000, 23726953550.7431, 
82200741495.4408, 12852987830.0144, 27045459856.5698, 314349098491, 
13394731629.6545, 1222623901.35877, 222011698915.434, 602372107459.307, 
170571688434.974, 43295270715.1102, 2.0558e+10, 39076122270.6046, 
54553954496.6018, 1.91942e+11, 72002887874.4588, 11089285874.2953, 
441833180000, 261831173341.6, 11646421263.4664, 3212491051.87374, 
220276557566.513, 227242774271.888, 12093527322.1487, 1.57445e+11, 
6.8731e+10, 7.9697e+10, 9270503494.65773, 107735282477.838, 3569254416.45001
), Import = c(68779495712.0305, 4537162833.55646, 254063849930.763, 
185620622249.928, 10236392000, 364143639834.488, 26931050000, 
3772597000, 3.68e+10, 6155587585.3598, 243660936841.03, 6633911658.6747, 
500163006070.577, 312065336933.79, 67820076191.149, 1380920299730.48, 
10775405646.026, 10705200000, 48046798936.1514, 15100529525.8354, 
130837451159.024, 1263115070306.35, 17797400000, 59862200000, 
383498000907.792, 13396203288.1648, 92754844880.5398, 752868287730.485, 
4923415827.48669, 749902578366.385, 13925330000, 322618256.760513, 
15213731418.538, 7775195685.41861, 22730499340.6279, 4287321211.20725, 
100281103545.836, 145424174547.834, 439059034248.05, 169386495216.739, 
47191500000, 76941100000, 577495808884.848, 6453776928.46442, 
18241408450.7042, 791792570423.91, 13531331102.0134, 512823900000, 
35354120068.3102, 868019609.325615, 30686400000, 24474123582.2915, 
67383739312.1496, 13173369811.9769, 36998738043.2765, 328707852420, 
13457646140.3091, 2642498673.22905, 181577107696.099, 532071517403.752, 
120110756464.812, 39973075650.9473, 21497300000, 34441341927.0994, 
65648068547.9856, 2.02076e+11, 89499906436.2193, 10292025283.6503, 
320958410000, 174203205866.667, 11371960452.1287, 5201250790.56075, 
196604177787.601, 207558530109.994, 6870500000, 1.97021e+11, 
5.6038e+10, 8.7294e+10, 10629016000, 102953525920.479, 6440274022.1819
), tradecost = c(2.8260194991743, 1.37233406139776, 2.22848303629037, 
1.02221684085353, 1.37512603597665, 0.655749277405991, 0.968892817917845, 
1.44874906814205, 0.888048411497731, 1.51237303563959, 4.64383709593806, 
1.07388433371409, 1.66438818365869, 0.85324394132387, 1.4591000014339, 
2.03934369088039, 1.0648662325473, 1.10188282287504, 3.04593397270418, 
0.917717435135471, 0.774554940050968, 1.25490968513045, 1.79128530602014, 
2.01381431167626, 1.8891732448602, 0.702439636210922, 1.32120533965529, 
1.80725668374763, 1.00665589955806, 1.70680093932396, 1.37718496509929, 
2.60169566919901, 1.58888147940729, 1.24576947916985, 1.32682049209118, 
1.24866310977131, 0.63196590081213, 2.41970440098524, 2.12886195453861, 
0.588900968251111, 1.36087024906885, 1.47726967863538, 1.91645671123355, 
1.26413906124506, 0.864572464690165, 3.43011138184821, 1.77664485890245, 
1.03292921698701, 1.03520759481992, 1.67468933328733, 0.934300180560614, 
0.768130518377497, 0.355735277650511, 0.914308434094678, 1.45550650516963, 
1.64495740864863, 0.32582482982176, 1.80062997656243, 0.631872353879062, 
0.746229143853026, 1.47500148698232, 1.76037879861251, 0.700037807363162, 
2.00671960926238, 1.66046103164356, 1.21649635435739, 1.47292131590025, 
1.27288585880015, 1.99912726940527, 1.21138888396621, 2.85137808763968, 
1.92721259568579, 1.18817824408527, 0.784507787988934, 1.1684199785098, 
2.17764685151773, 3.15136255408517, 0.694239508100683, 1.553140493745, 
1.781534793854, 1.20301923050891), skills = c(9.48, 10.87, 11.77, 
9.89, 10.5, 10.78, 11.45, 11.5, 12, 7.77, 7.66, 8.87, 12.56, 
13.42, 9.71, 7.53, 4.22, 3.61, 8.45, 11.11, 13.16, 12.69, 7.46, 
6.55, 10.3, 12.48, 10.21, 10.64, 7.57, 12.32, 6.76, 2.82, 4.3, 
5.5, 11.42, 4.74, 12.14, 7.26, 5.39, 12.2, 6.38, 12.76, 9.54, 
9.67, 9.21, 11.52, 6.19, 11.89, 6.26, 4.09, 7.31, 11.05, 11.22, 
10.48, 4.24, 8.33, 10.33, 4.29, 9.75, 11.6, 11.8, 11.3, 9.15, 
8.68, 8.18, 11.42, 7.2, 7.24, 11.73, 7.79, 3.13, 2.4, 11.89, 
7.3, 10.37, 6.56, 8.16, 7.45, 2.6, 9.43, 7.25), investmentcost = c(0.509259283542633, 
0.333333343267441, 0.916666686534882, 0.944444417953491, 0.416666686534882, 
0.833333313465118, 0.5, 0.694444477558136, 0.416666686534882, 
0.444444447755814, 0.384259253740311, 0.527777791023254, 0.916666686534882, 
0.861111104488373, 0.75, 0.472222208976746, 0.305555552244186, 
0.111111111938953, 0.365740746259689, 0.833333313465118, 0.6875, 
0.833333313465118, 0.305555552244186, 0.472222238779068, 0.766203701496124, 
0.597222208976746, 1, 0.67592591047287, 0.388888895511627, 0.916666686534882, 
0.416666656732559, 0.587962985038757, 0.356481492519379, 0.395833343267441, 
0.694444417953491, 0.16666667163372, 0.722222208976746, 0.333333343267441, 
0.555555582046509, 0.861111104488373, 0.16666667163372, 0.777777791023254, 
0.576388895511627, 0.418981492519379, 0.555555582046509, 0.805555522441864, 
0.375, 0.592592597007751, 0.555555582046509, 0.222222223877907, 
0.416666686534882, 0.569444417953491, 0.944444417953491, 0.597222208976746, 
0.666666686534882, 0.472222238779068, 0.694444417953491, 0.446759253740311, 
0.555555582046509, 0.944444417953491, 0.944444417953491, 0.972222208976746, 
0.444444447755814, 0.444444447755814, 0.444444447755814, 0.583333373069763, 
0.722222208976746, 0.259259283542633, 0.328703701496124, 0.555555582046509, 
0.277777791023254, 0.388888895511627, 0.972222208976746, 0.527777791023254, 
0.592592597007751, 0.5, 0.287037044763565, 0.472222238779068, 
0.305555552244186, 0.405092597007751, 0.194444447755814), distance = c(8403.226, 
9416.022, 15961.95, 15961.95, 9695.539, 6222.864, 7920.095, 1534.43, 
7450.31, 6565.147, 6794.436, 12786.42, 737.0425, 6603.182, 8080.885, 
11159.25, 7959.889, 10512, 3815.184, 9121.958, 6904.571, 6717.542, 
2371.688, 9357.814, 6092.003, 6972.001, 6943.182, 6169.154, 9679.682, 
5901.343, 8482.468, 6524.287, 3004.99, 2935.833, 7240.354, 2305.789, 
7342.427, 16371.12, 12059.81, 5448.801, 9981.358, 9450.717, 7224.739, 
2326.271, 9540.523, 10918.79, 12152.02, 11185.97, 10539.89, 7523.652, 
7818.324, 7280.807, 6393.923, 7081.517, 6146.918, 3037.916, 7729.347, 
12780.82, 15357.34, 6196.851, 6239.55, 14219.82, 3339.086, 5672.588, 
13794.33, 7183.616, 5740.448, 7414.781, 7834.547, 10858.59, 10544.13, 
6376.861, 6644.253, 14173.7, 3498.427, 8732.645, 3303.033, 13362.15, 
11448.37, 13040.41, 12793.88)), row.names = c(NA, -81L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worldmap` is:

```
> nrow(worldmap)
[1] 243
```

243 rows, ie all the countries in the world. So your nearest neighbour computations are amongst all 243 countries. The resulting network is:

```
> PPV3.w
Characteristics of weights list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 243
```

243 objects. Okay. Now your `database` is only 81 objects. That's why this fails:

```
moran.plot((database$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE)
```

the first argument is for 81 objects and the second is for 243.

This attempt fails:

```
moran.plot(my.na.omit(worldmap@data$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE)
```

because you've stripped out all the NA values from the 243 in `worldmap` and left yourself again with 81. Different length again, so you get that error.

I *think* what you need to do is to do the nearest neighbour graph on the 81 countries where you do have data. I'm not sure it makes sense to compute these indices regarding countries with missing data.

Extract the 81 countries with non-missing data:

```
> worldmap = worldmap[!is.na(worldmap$sales2010),]
```

Repeat the construction of the network:

```
> coor <- coordinates(worldmap)
> cartePPV3.knn <- knearneigh(coor, k=3) 
> cartePPV3.nb <- knn2nb(cartePPV3.knn)
> PPV3.w <- nb2listw(cartePPV3.nb, style = "W", zero.policy = TRUE)
```

That leaves you with a network list for 81 objects:

```
> PPV3.w
Characteristics of weights list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 81
```

And plotting works:

```
moran.plot(worldmap$sales2010, PPV3.w, zero.policy=TRUE)
```

I'm making a big assumption here that this is what you want, because its hard to know what to do with the missing data. The 81 regions don't seem to be a contiguous block (eg USA is missing, but Canada and Mexico are in there) and without some understanding of what the model you have in mind is then I don't think there's much more we can do here.